# While loop condition

Tags: python, while-loop

This is a really basic question, and I apologize for its simplicity, but I have been searching for the answer and trying different syntax for hours without luck.

I am using python to create a text menu for a cipher program. I am using a while loop for an error message when an invalid key is pressed, but it loops even when the condition is false.

```
purpose = input("Type 'C' for coding and 'D' for decoding: ")

while purpose.upper() != "D" or "C":
    purpose = input("Error, please type a 'C' or a 'D': ")

if (purpose.upper() == "C"):
    do_something()

if (purpose.upper() == "D"):
    do_something()
```

For some reason the error message is displayed regardless of key press.
Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
while purpose.upper() != "D" or "C":
```

to:

```
while purpose.upper() != "D" and purpose.upper() != "C":
```

As Saish suggested in the comments below, a more pythonic way of doing that would be:

```
while purpose.upper() not in ("C", "D"):
```

Comment: The pythonic way of doing this is really:
`while purpose.upper() not in ("C", "D"):`

Comment: @Saish +1 very true! (answer updated)

Answer (score 3):

You need to think of conditions on either side of `or` and `and` as logically independent.

When the computer sees:

```
while purpose.upper() != "D" or "C":
```

It reads it as

```
(purpose.upper() != "D")
```

OR

```
"C"
```

The second part, `"C"` alone, is always true.

---

You probably wanted:

```
while purpose.upper() != "D" or purpose.upper() != "C":
```

or better yet:

```
while purpose.upper() not in ("C", "D"):
```

Comment: The last option will return `True` when the user enters `CD` :)

Comment: @alfasin - Good point, I assumed it was a char.  I'll fix it :P

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this one. it seems to work

```
 reason = ['D', 'C']
 while True:
     purpose = input("Type 'C' for coding and 'D' for decoding: ").upper()
     if reason.__contains__(purpose):
         print("You've got it this time")
         break
```

Let me know how it works out

Answer (score 0):

```
while purpose.upper() != "D" or "C":
```

The above line will be evaluated to :

```
while (purpose.upper() != "D") or "C":
```

Expressions are evaluated left to right. Here "C" is always true, hence the loop is always executed.

You need to have something like this:

```
while purpose.upper() != "D" or purpose.upper() != "C":
```

or

```
#You can put it all into a list ["C", "D"] and then check 
while purpose.upper() not in ["C", "D"]:
```

or

```
#You can put it all into a tuple ("C", "D") and then check 
while purpose.upper() not in ("C", "D"):
```